# Tablesorter bootstrap not working after clicking one time on a specific column

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tablesorter

I have a web page, if I implement this `tablesorter` function. Upon clicking on a column tablesorter icon, it will sort one time. But if I will return to click on the the same column table sorter icon, it is not working. I have to click on another column for the sort to work. Could someone help me with it?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<!-- choose a theme file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.default.css">
<!-- load jQuery and tablesorter scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>

<!-- tablesorter widgets (optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Due</th>
      <th>Web Site</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td>
      <td>$50.00</td>
      <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bach</td>
      <td>Frank</td>
      <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td>
      <td>$50.00</td>
      <td>http://www.frank.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>Jason</td>
      <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td>
      <td>$100.00</td>
      <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Conway</td>
      <td>Tim</td>
      <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td>
      <td>$50.00</td>
      <td>http://www.timconway.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>

$(function(){
      $("#myTable").tablesorter({ sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]] });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your issue? It will be helpful, if you create a JSFiddle for the same.

Answer (score 0):

To add a Bootstrap theme:

- Load `bootstrap.css` (Bootstrap itself).
- Load `theme.bootstrap.css` (tablesorter theme).
- Include either `jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js`, or `widget-uitheme.js`.
- Include an `{icon}` definition in the `headerTemplate` setting
- Initialize the `uithene` widget.

Here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/njj5b5vc/70/).

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'bootstrap',
        headerTemplate: '{content}{icon}',
        widgets: ['uitheme']
    });
});
```

The "zebra" widget will only need to be included if you plan to use the filter widget - read the notes in [this demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-bootstrap-theme.html) to find out why.